# vueify (in gulp task) with babel transform of vue files

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, vue.js, browserify, vueify

fixed.

The solution is to:

1. pass through `.transform(babelify)` as well
2. ensure all your `.vue`-file script elements look like `<script type="text/javascript">` -- that *type* attribute must come **before** custom attributes, lang attribute.. might ahve to be the first, even only attribute on the tag.

I *think* my problem is that I have es6 in my vues. I am getting:

```
[09:33:36] Starting 'public'...

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "s
tart"
```

That error doesn't really tell me where it is coming from (my understanding is that it is from browserify), but if I null-op the public script the rest of the build works. Here's that script:

```
gulp.task('public', ['public/styles'], () => {
    mkdirp.sync(dest+'/public/scripts')
    return browserify('public/scripts/demo.js')
        .transform(vueify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest+'/public/scripts/index.js'))
})
```

That's basically copied from the readme.MD for vueify. Its dependency `public/styles` definitely does work.

So, I thought, let's try to compile them manually. I ensured I have babel-core and babel-preset-latest. Then: built the files:

#### .babelrc

`{ "presets": ["latest"]}`

#### vue.config.js

```
var babel = require("babel-core");

module.exports = {
    customCompilers: {
    // for tags with lang="es6"
    es6: function (content, cb, compiler, filePath) {
      // content:  content extracted from lang="es6" blocks
      // cb:       the callback to call when you're done compiling
      // compiler: the vueify compiler instance
      // filePath: the path for the file being compiled
      //
      // compile some ES6... and when you're done:
      const babelified = babel.transform(content) // what to do with this funky babelified.map ?
      cb(null, babelified.code)
    }
}
```

That's basically straight out of the readme.MD, but for es6.

Then I changed my vues to have that tag, like:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <app-header></app-header>
        <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12">
            <transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </transition>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="es6">
    import Header from './Header.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            appHeader: Header
        },
        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('initClasses')
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    body {
        padding: 5vmin;
    }

    .slide-enter-active { animation: slide-in 200ms ease-out forwards }
    .slide-leave-active { animation: slide-out 200ms ease-out forwards }
    @keyframes slide-in {
        from { transform: translateY(-30vmin); opacity: 0 }
        to { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 1}
    }
    @keyframes slide-out {
        from { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 1 }
        to { transform: translateY(-30vmin); opacity: 0}
    }
</style>
```

Problem is, I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

### ADDENDUMS IN RESPONSE

If I follow the advice below I get an error with import statements in my `vue`, in processing my main js file `demo.js`.

#### package.json's dev deps

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.22.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^14.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-clean-dest": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-vueify": "0.0.3",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "vueify": "^9.4.0"
  },
```

#### nearly fixed.

With help, I've gotten babelify not choking on vues. This was actually pretty obscure but simple, just get rid of the `lang` attribute and add `type="text/javascript"` to each script tag. (Couldn't just add that type specification, it has to be the *first* tag in the script element).

It almost works. Now I get:

```
[14:04:32] Starting 'public'...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module './vues/Home.vue' from 'C:\Users\roberto\github\cmst385-accessibility\public\scripts'
```

That is not the main js file! It's in `routes.js`

### in main I have:

```
import App from './vues/App.vue'
import {routes} from './routes'
```

*both* of these work.

### in routes I have:

```
import Home from './vues/Home.vue';
```

this does not work even though the file is there.

## BINGO

okay so I had actually named the file "Home..vue"  :)

Comment: I tried getting `babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx` up but that has trouble with the import statements being nested (they are not top level when transformed as jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to:

1. pass through `.transform(babelify)` as well (or do as listed in description and set it to go through babelify in package.json)
2. ensure all your `.vue`-file script elements look like `<script type="text/javascript">` -- that *type* attribute must come **before** custom attributes, lang attribute.. might ahve to be the first, even only attribute on the tag.

Answer (score 3):

These things are always difficult to debug without seeing the project, but I can show you how I set mine up, and you can check whether you have all these things in place:

Firstly, make sure you can use `ES6` in your `gulpfile`. The easiest way is to name it  `gulpfile.babel.js`. I'm guessing you already have this setup as you are managing to compile your `styles`.

Now, make sure that you have installed `babel-latest`, once again I'm sure you have done this:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-latest
```

I actually use the [babel-es2015-preset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015), so if you find `latest` is your problem simply install that instead and add the following to your `.babelrc`:

```
{ 
"presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Now, make sure you have installed `babelify`:

```
npm install --save-dev babelify
```

Then add the following to `package.json`:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "vueify"
    ]
  }
```

This means you can get rid of `vue.config.js` because `browserify` should now apply the transforms automatically.

Finally in your gulpfile you can do:

```
gulp.task('public', ['public/styles'], () => {
   return browserify({
            entries: 'public/scripts/demo.js',
            debug: true
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('demo.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/scripts'));
});
```

I've never needed to add the `lang` attribute to the `script` tag to get this working.

Comment: voting you up for the details. thank you. Which vinyl source is that, stream? I get `Error: Parsing file C:\Users\roberto\github\cmst385-accessibility\public\scripts\vues\App.vue: 'import' and 'export' m
ay only appear at the top level (5:0)` doing this.

Comment: _ps>_ added my dev dependencies - can you compare versions, maybe this is a problem with browserify version. _pps>_ why did you think to use babelify at all? The vueify documentation makes the claim very clearly that it does not need additional config, if babel-core is present it will use it even against your wishes (not sure that's happening, but..).

Comment: That's possible, I'm using `browserify 13.1.1`. It does look like your issue is with transpiling `ES6`. I do have a recent project on GitHub, so you can take a look at my [package.json here](https://github.com/craigh411/vue-star-rating/blob/master/package.json#L30) which you might find helpful.

Comment: I forked your repo and ran it, and it works fine. then I swapped your src/ directory for mine, and I get the same "App.vue" error. Then I noticed all your vue `<script>` tags have "type="text/javascrirpt"` so I added them and .. nothing happened. But then I also _removed_ my language tag so that the element looks exactly the same (nothing between script and type) and voila! A different error: `Error: Cannot find module './vues/Home.vue' from 'C:\Users\roberto\github\cmst385-accessibility\public\scripts'` - this is not from the topfile, but from `import routes` in it. Almost working now.

Comment: got it :) that was all I needed from before, I just had a typo in the filename on disk.