# VueJS Component import failed

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a simple demo I wanna try out to learn more about VueJS components. But when I load my page, I receive the error: Unexpected Token Import, in this line

import GISView from './components/GISView.vue';

when I remove this, GISView is not defined. I use Laravel 5.4 and webpack for compiling the scripts. Why is the component not found?

**Main.js**

```
import GISView from './components/GISView.vue';

window.Vue = Vue;
window.Event = new class {
    constructor() {
        this.Vue = new Vue();
    }

    fire(event, data = null) {
        this.Vue.$emit(event, data);
    }

    listen(event, callback) {
        this.Vue.$on(event, callback);
    }
};

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        GISView: GISView
    },
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
        init: function() {
            this.$broadcast('MapsApiLoaded');
        }
    }
});
```

**GISView.vue**

```
<script>
    import GoogleMaps from '../mixins/GoogleMaps.js';

    export default {
        mixins: [GoogleMaps]
    }
</script>
```

I really got stuck for hours on this because just by the code, it should work I would say.

Comment: Please post the loaders section of your webpack config

Answer (score -3):

You are not using a proper parser like vueify to properly parse .vue files in your webpack/gulp script.

Comment: How would I add that?

Comment: see the answers to my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005463/vueify-in-gulp-task-with-babel-transform-of-vue-files/42028255#42028255

Comment: This is incorrect.  The OP doesn't appear to be using gulp and would be able to far more easily vue-loader over vueify into a webpack pipeline.  In addition, this doesn't actually answer the OP's question  At best it is a comment.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: @DavidL it is not complete, definitely, but no need to down vote. He needs an equivalent solution for his build process. Until he posts details on what that is, there's no way for me to improve my answer.. In fact if he is using gulp then my answer is very likely correct.